# Mathematica Maximization, Won't maximize a * 0.3

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, mathematica-8, mathematica-frontend

I'm Having a problem maximizing this function in mathematica:

```
Maximize[a + 0.3 * b, 0 < b < 10, a]
```

I just get the above back again as output when I run the code, Not helpfull

However when I maximize the equivalent function:

```
Maximize[a + (3/10) * b, 0 < b < 10, a]
```

I get a solution?!?

What is going on here? why does mathematica do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare these results you see that the first one switches to use `NMaximize` due to `0.3` being `Real`, whereas the second attempts to solve symbolically using `Maximise` due to `3/10` being `Rational`.  This accounts for the different behaviour.

[image]

```
Map[Head, {0.3, 3/10}]
```

> {Real, Rational}

Comment: This seams to explain the issue, but why does mathematica not try to do this on its own is beyond me. And the lack of debugging output is worrying